# Cross-platform jvm launcher?

Tags: java

I'm looking at http://akuma.kohsuke.org/, but it's only for POSIX systems. I don't need daemonization, just an orderly way to launch more jvms from a java program. Yes, ProcessBuilder, but how do I find the right java.exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System property `java.home` contains path to current java home. For example on my computer it is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre.
So, the following statement `System.getProperty("java.home") + "/bin/java"` should give you the fully qualified path to your current JVM.

If you want to be even more cross platform use File.separator instead of slash.